# Create multiple rows based on repeated columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a csv (technically, an Excel spreadsheet) that has rows/columns like this:

```
AC-10   ECLO-1  ECLO-2
AC-11   PESL-1  
AC-13   ABCD-2  ABDE-3  AGTU-5
```

What I'd like to do is create two columns so that it looks like this:

```
AC-10   ECLO-1  
AC-10   ECLO-2    <- Notice the 'AC-10' is now repeated with the (former) 3rd column as its value
AC-11   PESL-1
AC-13   ABCD-2  
AC-13   ABDE-3    <- Repeated row, new value from old column
AC-13   AGTU-5    <- Repeated row, same idea
```

Is there a relatively pain-free way to do this in Excel? I'm trying to avoid scripting out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: All references from memory! No Excel available, script testing not possible.

The simplest approach:

- Click/Select cell `ECLO-2`
- Find 'Record macro' - at the same place you'll find `Use relative references` do activate it...
- and then `Record Macro`, select a shortcut key to use and then click <kbd>OK</kbd> to start recording.
- Press <kbd>cursor down</kbd>
- Find and use `Insert Row` in menus (using shortcut keys: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>)
- <kbd>cursor up</kbd>  *(back on top of ECLO-2 again)*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
- <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>cursor down</kbd>
- <kbd>cursor right</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>cursor up</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- <kbd>cursor down</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- <kbd>cursor up</kbd>
- <kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>cursor right</kbd>
- Click `Stop recording`

If I typed the above correctly, and you got it right; you should now have

```
AC-10   [ECLO-1]        
AC-10   ECLO-2      
AC-11   PESL-1      
AC-13   ABCD-2  ABDE-3  AGTU-5
```

with the cursor on the ECLO-1 cell as indicated by the [brackets].

To use the just recorded shortcut key, move the cursor to `AGTU-5` and then use the shortcut.
That will launch the macro and place AGTU-5 on the line below in the manner you wanted. The last actions of the macro should leave the cursor on top of `ABDE-3`, ready for one more launch.

*I hope I got it right, had I had an Excel available then it would have been tested too ;-)

Hope it gives you the idea at least.*